# Loading twitter hashtag feed in UIWebView

Tags: ios, twitter, uiwebview, hashtag

I'm trying to load a Twitter hashtag feed (e.g. http://www.twitter.com/#technology) in a UIWebView. But I just get re-directed to the Twitter login page. When I try the same on Chrome or Safari, I get similarly directed to the login page, but then it quickly redirects to the hashtag feed.

Is there any way to ensure my UIWebView redirects the same way, so I can show the hashtag feed page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the specific mobile view.  This should prevent Twitter from trying to redirect you to log in.

```
https://mobile.twitter.com/search/%23hashtag
```

Comment: Not working now, even in Safari mobile says too many redirects!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create the feed yourself? You can post a request to twitter's JSON search and post the values in your own way without requiring a UIWebView.

The link is http://search.twitter.com/search.json? and the search parameter is q, so http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23hashtag will search for '#hashtag'.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but a bit overkill for what I have in mind. I've already pulled a particular feed into a tableview, and just want to provide a simple courtesy view of hashtags and links tapped on from within the tableviewcell. But again, a good solution for a more formal implementation. Thanks!